# How can I retrieve the logs for a specific Azure Durable Function run?

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-durable-functions

My function has many steps. One of the 1st things I do is create a database record where I store the context.InstanceId for that particular run.  Using application insights I figured out how to go into TransactionSearch and use that instance id to query for specifics for that run, but all I see is basic info like scheduled, started, completed, etc for the various tasks.  How can I get access to the logs I see when I open LogStream and switch to FileSystemLogs?  There I can see everything my function is logging like debug and information statements.

I'd like to be able to somehow extract exactly what I would have seen if I had had the LogStream window open.

EDIT: I know how to find the logs through the portal, kind of.  It's tedious.  My function gets called 1000 times a day and maybe one or two fail.

When I have the portal log stream open set to filesystem, and I do one test run, I can see a nice clear log of everything that was done. Now in production, if I open log stream it's a cluttered mess.

Let me clarify my question:

1. Is there any way at the end of a function run to programmatically query and pull all the log entries that were logged during that run of that specific function instance (including all activities) so that I can package up into an email?
2. Or can I query a specific api call with function instance id after the fact?
3. I can see the file system log stream but where can I find the raw file being saved?  When I go to the azure storage, I can see some log files, but they have almost no content.  The only time I found a file is when I had a portal filesystem log stream console open and then it seemed to write to the log file.  Is there any way to get it to log all the time?

Comment: Which version of Azure function you are using?Could you please share the code and configuration file?

Comment: I'm using 4.24.3.21050

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample Azure Durable function and able to log traces to Application Insights.

Install the below NuGet Packages

```cs
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService
```

***Packages in my `.csproj` file:***

```cs
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" Version="2.21.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService" Version="2.15.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions" Version="1.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.18.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.0.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.13.0" />
```

Configure `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService` in `ConfigureServices` and `AddApplicationInsights` in `ConfigureLogging`.

***My program.cs file:***

```cs
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
     .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
     .AddJsonFile("local.settings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
     .Build();

var Conn = configuration["ApplicationInsights:ConnectionString"];

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService(
            options => options.ConnectionString = Conn);
        services.AddLogging();
    
    })
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.AddApplicationInsights();
    })
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

You can either use `local.settings.json` or `host.json` file to configure Application Insights.

***My `local.settings.json` file:***

```cs
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated",
    "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "**********
  },

  //configure local.settings.json for app insights 
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=**********;IngestionEndpoint=https://****-2.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://****.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  }
}
```

***My Sample `Function1.cs`***

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.DurableTask;
using Microsoft.DurableTask.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp2
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [Function(nameof(Function1))]
        public static async Task<List<string>> RunOrchestrator(
            [OrchestrationTrigger] TaskOrchestrationContext context)
        {
            ILogger logger = context.CreateReplaySafeLogger(nameof(Function1));
            logger.LogInformation("Saying hello.");
            var outputs = new List<string>();
          
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Tokyo"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "Seattle"));
            outputs.Add(await context.CallActivityAsync<string>(nameof(SayHello), "London"));
       
            return outputs;
        }

        [Function(nameof(SayHello))]
        public static string SayHello([ActivityTrigger] string name, FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("SayHello");
            logger.LogInformation("Saying hello to {name}.", name);
            return $"Hello {name}!";
        }

        [Function("Function1_HttpStart")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseData> HttpStart(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req,
            [DurableClient] DurableTaskClient client,
            FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            ILogger logger = executionContext.GetLogger("Function1_HttpStart");
          
            string instanceId = await client.ScheduleNewOrchestrationInstanceAsync(
                nameof(Function1));

            logger.LogInformation("Started orchestration with ID = '{instanceId}'.", instanceId);         
            return client.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId);
        }
    }
}
```

- Deploy the app to Azure Functions.

[image]

- Execute the Function URL's.

***Log Stream:***

[image]

***Traces in Application Insights Transcation Search:***

[image]

Comment: I appreciate all of the work you put into the above.  My function already logs and I can find them in portal search.  It is tedious scrolling through tons of logs entries like that.  However you did a transaction search for "ALL".  Is there a way I can programmatically get the logs via an api to recreate what is seen in your second to last screenshot of the log stream for ONE SPECIFIC instance run of a function (including all it's child activities)?  I would like to recreate a nice clean summarized log stream of a specific run that looks just like the log stream window output.